# New to c, linking error when using a method declared in a header that's included

Tags: c, linker, ld

I'm new to c and I'm trying to use a method from tester in my main.c class.

So here is main.c:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "tester.h"

int main(void) {
    bool is_valid = isTrue();
}
```

Here is tester.h:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isTrue();
```

Here is tester.c:

```
#include "tester.h"

bool isTrue() {
    return true;
    }
```

And here is what happens when I try to compile:

```
$ make main tester
gcc -g -O0 -Wall --std=c99 -pedantic  -g -O0  main.c   -o main
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:10: warning: unused variable ‘is_valid’ [-Wunused-variable]
     bool is_valid = isTrue();
          ^
/tmp/ccwIzgJQ.o: In function `main':
/home/paul/CS261/p1-check/mess/main.c:7: undefined reference to `isTrue'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

My Makefile was provided by my professor. I can post the contents here, but I'm confident it's correct. I know there's a linking error happening here, but why? I included the tester.h file in my main.c, so shouldn't isTrue be defined? Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the Makefile:

```
# Simple Makefile
# 
#
# This makefile builds a simple application that contains a main module
# (specified by the EXE variable) and a predefined list of additional modules
# (specified by the MODS variable). If there are any external library
# dependencies (e.g., the math library, "-lm"), list them in the LIBS variable.
# If there are any precompiled object files, list them in the OBJS variable.
#
# By default, this makefile will build the project with debugging symbols and
# without optimization. To change this, edit or remove the "-g" and "-O0"
# options in CFLAGS and LDFLAGS accordingly.
#
# By default, this makefile build the application using the GNU C compiler,
# adhering to the C99 standard with all warnings enabled.


# application-specific settings and run target

EXE=y86
MODS=p1-check.o
OBJS=
LIBS=

default: $(EXE)

test: $(EXE)
    make -C tests test

# compiler/linker settings

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -O0 -Wall --std=c99 -pedantic
LDFLAGS=-g -O0


# build targets

$(EXE): main.o $(MODS) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXE) $^ $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

clean:
    rm -f $(EXE) main.o $(MODS)
    make -C tests clean

.PHONY: default clean
```

Am I missing a part of the command when I try to use the Makefile for linking? It's probably something on my end, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: `but I'm confident it's correct.`, nopes, it is not correct.

Comment: `gcc -g -O0 -Wall --std=c99 -pedantic  -g -O0  main.c   -o main` should be `gcc -g -O0 -Wall --std=c99 -pedantic  -g -O0  main.c tester.c  -o main`

Comment: No, you do need to show the makefile. It's either incorrect or not set up for you to use a seperate `tester.c` file. And you need to learn the difference between declarations (in header files) and definitions (in C files). Declarations tell the compiler "the function exists" and definitions tell the compiler "this is the implementation". So including the header only is not enough. When linking, the definitions are needed.

Comment: Add `tester.o` to `MODS`. That is `MODS=p1-check.o tester.o`.

Comment: I put it in there! My terminal now says `$ make main tester
make: *** No rule to make target `main'.  Stop.`

Comment: You really need to read the [Makefile documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and/or do a basic Makefile tutorial. It's not productive for SO to teach you basics step by step. The Makefile does not have a `main` target. Try just `make` by itself (builds default rule) or `make y86`.

Comment: Try changing the line `OBJS=` to `OBJS=tester.o`.  Then go follow the advice that kaylum gave you.  Really, we (well at least I) really, really mean it.

Comment: @thurizas To be entirely correct `tester.o` needs to go in `MODS` rather than `OBJS` due to the way the Makefile is written. It'll still (mostly) work if put in `OBJS`. The comments tell us that `OBJS` is for precompiled objects and thus they are not removed as part of the `clean` rule.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum. I read up on Makefile and understand where I was going wrong now. I appreciate the patience.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I should have been saying make main.o when I wanted to link files with it. I wasn't paying enough attention to the build commands in Makefile, it seems. Thanks to kaylum for the clarification between declarations and definitions.